# Standard Class Names and ID names in CSS

Tags: navigation

how can i learn the **CSS** standard class names and id names?
forexample

```html
<div class="nav_toggle" id="nav-toggle">
          <i class="bx bx-menu"></i>
        </div>
```

names like nav_toggle and the rest